# An exception occurred when instantiating a COM object

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have upgraded from ColdFusion 6 to ColdFusion 10 and I'm encountering the following error:

> An exception occurred when instantiating a COM object
>
> The cause of this exception was that: coldfusion.runtime.com.ComObjectInstantiationException: An exception occurred when instantiating a COM object.

My call to the COM object:

```
<cfobject 
  type="COM" 
  action="create" 
  context="INPROC" 
  class="ASIUtil.Ccrypting" 
  name="crypting"
>
```

My ColdFusion runs on 32 bit and I know that ColdFusion 64 bit does not support COM interoperability. But Even though my ColdFusion is 32 bit I am encountering this problem.

Please help me find a way to make this work.

Comment: What OS? CF on Unix [does not support COM objects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6e.html).

Comment: Windows 7...I'm not using unix...

Comment: Possibly a permissions issue or dll registration error if you have upgraded Windows as well? I would try your google fu with .NET instead of ColdFusion to try to find some clues.

Comment: *Windows 7* 64bit or 32bit? Also, that is a boiler plate error message. Did you check the cf and o/s logs for more details?

Comment: @J.T. Yup...Anyways Thank you for the help... :)

Comment: @Leigh Its windows 32 Bit...

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with ColdFusion. All you have to do is to register the DLL. I have faced this problem too and after registering them, the object creation worked.

```
regsvr32 asiutil.dll
```

**Important**

Before you do the registration, make sure you back up any conflicting DLL and also, sometimes the DLL are locked because they are in use, so you may need to restart the server.